# React onClick not firing at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, jsx

I have an anchor tag with an onClick in a component being rendered by another component. It looks like this:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" 
className="btn btn-link" 
onClick={this.closeThing.bind(this)}>Close</a>`

this.closeThing is defined, and when I use React Dev tools I can see that it knows about the onClick. But no onClick here works, even if I change to an anonymous function that just logs gibberish to test. No matter what function I want to occur upon click, nothing happens when I click "Close".

I have tried taking the event in as a param and calling `e.preventDefault` first thing in the function.

I am using ES6 class syntax to declare React components.

Has anyone else run into this? It's mind boggling.

Oh, also this used to work, but the only thing I changed now is I've changed it from a jsx file to a js file because I am using System.js to take advantage of ES6 modules. But everything is fine except the onClick does not work.

EDIT: Problem seems to have been that I had two different "instances" of React loaded on the page. :T One from ES6 module and one from CDN URL. Switching the CDN URL to a System.js import solved the problem.

Comment: Try `onClick={() => this.closeThing()}`

Comment: It may not solve the problem fully, but I'd recommend switching to a `<div>` or `<span>` instead of an anchor and removing the href.  You can always stylize it as a link using CSS.

Comment: I second what @Scott recommended. After all, you're building an app, not a web page.. think of it that way. I can't even remember the last time I used an `<a href>` in a React app.

Comment: Thanks @ffxsam, it seems I only code in DIVs these days :)

Comment: Yep, same here. All divs and buttons!

Comment: @ssaeed, try adding a click handler to your `body` tag and alerting/logging what is the event.target to see if some other element is capturing the click.

Answer (score 0):

Is it showing any exceptions in browser's console? It also can be UI issue may be your close area element is overlayed by some transparent element which is not allowing to click on the actual element..

Comment: This isn't an answer and should be something to post as a comment

Comment: @NickZuber but it is quite useful ,some absolute element overlaying can cause the problem and it is the case for me

Comment: @Guigui I didn't say it wasn't useful, I said it wasn't an answer — I think Ali's commentary was very valuable, but not appropriate as an answer